# Date javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to understand more about the Date object in javascript.
I thought that when you call valueOf(), you get the amount of milliseconds since january 1, 1970.
So what I would expect is that the following should return exactly zero;

```
alert((new Date(1970, 1, 1).valueOf() )/ ( 86400 * 1000));
```

but it does not, it returns 30.958333333333332. What am I missing?

gr,

Coen

Comment: As a question, how did you expect to get zero from a division?

Comment: @Stephen, it's oddly stated, but I think he was expecting the numerator to be 0.  No idea why the division is in there though...

Comment: @Reinis I. - Possibly badly worded, yes, but what I was trying to say is that a division is only 0 if the numerator is 0. So, if he expects the result to be 0, why divide? Just return the numerator. @Kendrick - Yeah, that was my point, albeit badly stated.

Comment: FYI `new Date(1970, 0, 1).valueOf()` is not guaranteed to be 0 either, unless the system clock is set to GMT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second parameter, month, starts with 0, so you need to do:

```
alert((new Date(1970, 0, 1).valueOf() )/ ( 86400 * 1000));
```

but even with this you'll get the offset, in seconds, off GMT.

the value you posted says you are `GMT +1`  : )

Comment: what is the rationale behind starting months with 0 and days with 1?

Comment: Read the answers to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393462/defend-zero-based-arrays).

Comment: We don't talk about zero. 
http://www.amazon.com/Zero-Biography-Dangerous-Charles-Seife/dp/0140296476

Answer (score 6):

new Date(1970, 1, 1) actually is Feb. Months are zero-indexed.  Try changing it to new Date(1970, 0, 1).

Comment: Jeez Javascript. Since when does anyone refer to January as the zeroth month?

Comment: @jessegavin: since 1996. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html which is what JavaScript's (actually JScript's) `Date` behavior was derived from.

Comment: Numbers should always start with 0, we live in a really messed up world. Just look at the inconsistency of just this constructor. First month is 0, first day is 1, first year is 1970, what the hell?? :p

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to work with the [unix epoch time](http://www.epochconverter.com/), you have a few options

- `UTC()` Returns the number of
  milliseconds in a date string since
  midnight of January 1, 1970,
  according to universal time
- `setTime()` Sets a date and time by
  adding or subtracting a specified
  number of milliseconds to/from
  midnight January 1, 1970
- `parse()` Parses a date string and
  returns the number of milliseconds
  since midnight of January 1, 1970
- `getTime()` Returns the number of
  milliseconds since midnight Jan 1,
  1970

`valueOf()` returns a primitive of the value, I'd stay away from it and work with the above options.

source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp.

edit: also, your asking for Feb 1, 1970

use this, it's dangerous to go alone:

```
var d=new Date(1970, 0, 1);
document.write(d.getTime());
```

or

```
var d= Date.parse("Jan 1, 1970"); //Note, we don't use NEW keyword.
document.write(d);
```

Remember, epcoh is Wed Dec 31 1969 19:00:00 GMT-0500. If you use `.getTime()` you'll see UTC time Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT +0000.

Comment: `valueOf()` returns a representation of the date in a primitive, which is a number in this case.  This makes `valueOf()` and `getTime()` equivalent for Date objects.

Comment: the following does not return either;

    alert(Date.parse("1970-1-1")/ ( 86400 * 1000))

Comment: @Coen: You should still use `0` as month parameter and it's better not to use the parser to set a date, just use `new Date(1970, 0, 1)`.

Comment: @AndyE .valueOf() returns a string, while .getTime() returns a number. This may seem moot, but with the direction of ecma-script, they may be moving to stricter types optionally. Source: ECMAScript 262 spec

Comment: @user: *valueOf()* doesn't return a string.  Like I said in my original comment, it returns a number primitive.  You can try this for yourself - `var test = new Date(); console.log(test.getTime() === test.valueOf())`.  Which version of and chapter in the ECMA-262 spec are you referring to?

Comment: So it looks like there's a bit of confusion with this...
15.2.4.4.2.a "Return either O or another value such as the host object originally passed to the constructor. The specific result that is returned is implementation-defined." The refrence I used to say it was a string was http://objjob.phrogz.net/js/object/224 and not http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf. I was wrong. I find it weird that this is implementation-defined however.

Comment: @user: *weird* is one word for it.  There are a lot of "implementation defined" functions in the spec and it really gets my goat! ;-) Fortunately, *valueOf()* for Date is one of the few the implementors agree on.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are searching is `.getTime(`) not `.valueOf()`

Comment: According to W3Schools, they are the same. A quick self-check - `<html><body><script type="text/javascript">var d=new Date();document.write(d.valueOf() + " milliseconds since 1970/01/01");</script></body></html>` shows that this works (for me, at this exact moment in time.) Do you have a source to contradict this?

Answer (score 0):

Months are zero based in Date objects.

Answer (score 0):

January 1st, 1970 is `new Date(1970, 0, 1)`, since months start at `0` = January.

Answer (score 0):

The first of january 1970 with the Date object is `new Date(1970, 0, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

it was the month that should have been 0 in combination with an hour difference from GMT

alert((new Date(1970, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).valueOf()));

produces 0